# How access dynamic added controls from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic-programming

I'm having a class which adds some controls into my web form.
Now i need to access dynamically added controls by my class.
Can any one tell me how can i access dynamically added controls from server side code.

Comment: Calling `FindControl` on the container. Or simply maintaining reference to the control (if possible).

Comment: @AshishRathore, any errors? Maybe some code?

Comment: container.FindControl always shows null

Comment: @AshishRathore, there might be myriads of reasons for that. Any specifics that you can share?

Comment: Actually i have an user control in that user control I'm adding some controls and events dynamically.When i use `FindControl` in any of the event with control's id it returns null.And it also returns 0 control count.

Comment: `FindControl` not working because i used `asp:Table` as container.My problem is solved by looping through all controls of my user control.
Because even I'm not able to find my container.

Comment: I've posted my answer.I know this is not a good answer can any one give me any answer beater then my this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've find a solution for problem.Looping through all controls.

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> GetControls(ControlCollection controlCollection)
{
    foreach (Control control in controlCollection)
    {
        yield return control;

        if (control.Controls == null || control.Controls.Count == 0)
            continue;

        foreach (var sub in GetControls(control.Controls))
        {
            yield return sub;
        }
    }
}
```

After creating IEnumerable list check for the Control's ID.

```
    foreach (Control c in ctr__)
    {
        if (c.ClientID == "dropUGrp")
        { 
           //Code goes here
           break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've added the Controls Dynamically then you already have a reference to the controls you've added; simply retain that reference.

If that isn't possible for some reason use, as others have already suggested, `FindControl("ID_OF_CONTROL")`.

But make sure you've set the `Id` of the control before you add it to the Controls collection. :

```
var tbItem = new TextBox();
tbItem.Id = "tbItem_Id";

// add to some place holder
phLocation.Controls.Add(tbItem);
```

You can now use `FindControl("tbItem_Id")` to reference the added Control.

If that fails, make sure you have a grasp on the lifecycle of the page & requests, you might find you've not actually added the controls by the time you search for it.

But I say again, you already have the reference, store it off and reuse it.

Comment: I have `Ajax:TabContainer` on my control and inside `tabpanal` i used `asp:Table` as container for my control.When i use WebUserControl.FindControl it doesn't find dynamically added control.For that problem I've posted a answer plz check that and provide me beter solution if u have.